Hide / Show RecyclerView Items after Activity Button Click
I have an indeterminate list of items (override fun getItemCount() = list.size). I would like to initially show only the position 0 item to the user. After I click the "View All" button outside the recyclerview but in my activity I would like to unhide the remaining items of my list.
I can get the initial part to work in onBindViewHolder:
if (position > 0) {
view.foo.visibility  = View.GONE 
}
else {
view.foo.visibility  = View.VISIBLE 
}

but I cannot figure out how to get the remaining items to show when I click the "View All" button.
I know I need a method in my adapter and to call that method in the activity ViewAll.onclickListnener. I am just not sure what to put in the adapter method or how it interacts with the conditions inside onBindViewHolder.
Is there any simple way to just change the list.size back and forth?
kotlin preferred if possible.
Edit:
class Adapter(private var list: List<Model>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>(){

internal fun setDataSet(list: ArrayList<Model>) {
    this.list = list
}

var showAll: Boolean = false


class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val textView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView)

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {    
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview, viewGroup, false)

    return ViewHolder(view)
}



 override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

val model = list[position]
        
if(showAll){
            println("showAll is triggered!")      
            viewHolder.textView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            viewHolder.textView.text = model.textView
        }else{
            viewHolder.textView.text = list[0].textView
            if (viewHolder.adapterPosition > 0){
                println("this is triggered!")
                viewHolder.textView.visibility = View.GONE             
            }
        }

    println("listsize at start: $size")
}

fun updateAdapter(showAll: Boolean) {
    this.showAll = showAll
    notifyDataSetChanged()
    println("listsize after click: $size")
}

override fun getItemCount() = list.size

}
MainActivity:
buttonPlus.setOnClickListener {
adapter.updateAdapter(true)
println("button pressed")
}

buttonMinus.setOnClickListener {
adapter.updateAdapter(false)
println("button pressed")
}

XML:
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/mainLL"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fooRL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleLL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/title />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/buttonPlus"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/buttonplus"
        android:src="@drawable/add_box_24" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/buttonMinus"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/buttonminus"
        android:src="@drawable/minus_box_24"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/headingsLL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="-10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/item"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:background="@drawable/recyclerview_data"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/recyclerview_item" />

</LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/noDataFound"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/recyclerview_data"
        android:text="@string/noDataFound"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
</LinearLayout>

Model Class:
data class Model(val textView: String)
Solution:
I added this inside my setOnClickListeners: recyclerview?.adapter = Adapter

In your MainActivity (EDIT)
val recyclerView: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
val buttonPlus: Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonPlus)
val buttonMinus: Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonMinus)


val dataSet = ArrayList<Model>()
dataSet.add(Model("value1"))
dataSet.add(Model("value2"))
dataSet.add(Model("value3"))
dataSet.add(Model("value4"))

val recyclerViewAdapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(dataSet)
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
recyclerView.adapter = recyclerViewAdapter

buttonPlus.setOnClickListener {
    recyclerViewAdapter.updateAdapter(true)
    Toast.makeText(this, "buttonPlus clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

buttonMinus.setOnClickListener {
    recyclerViewAdapter.updateAdapter(false)
    Toast.makeText(this, "buttonMinus clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

In RecyclerViewAdapter create a class variable to check if items should be hidden or visible and also a function to update your adapter.
fun updateAdapter(showAll: Boolean){
    this.showAll = showAll
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

In onBindViewHolder() hide items if the adapter position is bigger than 0.
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if(showAll){
        holder.textView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        holder.textView.text = list[position]
    }else{
        holder.textView.text = list[0]
        if (holder.adapterPosition > 0){
            holder.textView.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
}

EDIT
in your layout/activity_main.xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#3D3A3A">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonPlus"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonPlus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Show"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/buttonMinus"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonMinus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hide"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/buttonPlus"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

in layout/recyclerview.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="12sp" />


Hi Vince, thank your for your answer. Similar to the other two answers it is displaying properly with 1 row from the start. I press my button and it does not seem to change the boolean value. If I manually go in and change the "showAll" to "!showAll" it shows the correct number of rows. There is clearly something I am doing wrong. I have the variable in my adapter as "var showAll: Boolean = false" is this correct?

@DJTalls Can you edit your post and add all code from your adapter so that i can take a look?

@DJTalls make sure you call  notifyDataSetChanged() after changing the boolean so that the recyclerview is refreshed and onBindViewHolder is called.

Just added code. Thank you for taking a look!

@DJTalls Just tried and it works fine for me, can you also add your model class and R.layout.reyclerview xml ?

@DJTalls does your model class contain textviews? because if not then list[0].textView in onbindviewholder would not show anything

yes it does. I have simplified my code, but it is a textView. I believe the list[0] does work because I changed it to list[1] and it showed the textview in the 2nd position.

for some reason the if(showAll) part does not get triggered after buttonPlus isclicked. I put a println() in there and in the actual onClickListener and it triggers on click, but the condition in if(showAll) does not work.

@DjTalls So for some reason showAll stays false, can you check this by adding a         Log.d("showAll", showAll.toString()) in your onbindviewholder. Then check your logcat with tag:showAll

@DjTalls can you also add the code from your R.layout.recyclerview

onCreate() it shows 4 false as there are 4 items. When I click buttonPlus it says true. When I click buttonMinus it says false. So it is working there. I just don;t know why the 3 other items in the list don't show up. I am adding some of my layout.

@DJTalls in onBindViewHolder if(showAll) is see that viewHolder.textView.text = list[position] but your list contains type Model. TextView.text needs a String type. Can you also add your Model class ?

sorry, I had to remove a lot of code to make it simple and made a mistake. I have updated my code. That is the styling I have in my code.

@DJTalls your activity_main layout does not make sense and i recommend using ConstraintLayout to avoid nesting so much views. I edited my post and added my layouts and from there you can add the other things you need.

Sorry for the ambiguity, but there are a lot of visual details I needed to leave out as this is a work project and there are much more than just 1 textview in each recyclerview item. I do not think the layout is the problem since if I just modify your code from if(showAll) to if(!showAll) it displays 1 item for the first one and 4 items for the second one. Using your Log inside the onBindViewHolder displayed that showAll changes from false to true, but it does not seem to change the above if(showAll) or if it does change it does not update correctly to reflect on my UI as it should.

@DJTalls can you check if onBindViewHolder()  is called after notifydatasetchanged() ? If i understand correctly it works if you manually change showAll to true or false?

@DJTalls just put a log outside the if/else statement and check how many times onBindViewHolder() is called.

I put the log after the if/esle. Initially I get 4 false and after clicking the button there are no new logs. I put another log before the if/else and I get 4 false initially and it switches to true after button click.

I think it may have to do with the list.size changing from 4 to 0 after click. I have no idea why this is happening, but this could explain why onBindViewHolder and the method inside is not triggered after onCreate happens. Any thoughts of what could make it go to 0?

I figured it out! Even though I had this inside my onCreate() I added: recyclerview?.adapter = Adapter inside my button.onClickListeners and it did the trick. Thanks so much for all your efforts. I almost gave up and reverted to a less fun way to show my data.

@DJTalls No problem, glad to hear it's working. Have a nice day :)

You need a variable in your adapter to save if all items filter is enabled
var isViewAllEnabled = false

And create a function in your adapter to change value of this new variable, is important call to notifyDataSetChanged() after update value for notify to adapter update list
fun updateIsViewAllEnabled(isViewAllEnabled: Boolean) {
  this.isViewAllEnabled = isViewAllEnabled
  notifyDataSetChanged()
}

In your activity you need call to this function after click in "View All" button:
ViewAll.setOnClickListener {
   myAdapter.updateIsViewAllEnabled(true)
}

And if you need show only first element of your adapter is not needed change visibility, you can override getItemCount function like this:
override fun getItemCount(): Int { 
  if (!isViewAllEnabled) {
     if (list.isNotEmpty()) {
        return 1
     } else {
        return 0
     }
  } else {
     return list.size
  }

}

Similar to the issue I had with the other answer I am getting it to display the first item only which is correct, but when I hit the View All button the additional items are not becoming visible.

Did you call to notifyDataSetChanged() after update value of isViewAllEnabled for notify to adapter update list? This line is essential for refresh list

yes, I did. I know the method gets triggered as I put in a println. Could it have to do with the getItemCount() part? It made me change from Boolean to Int there

Modifying the getItemCount() method with hardcoded values instead of items count is an evil practice.

You could debug if getItemCount() is called after call to notifyDataSetChanged(). In case that is called and item count returns right size of the list, you can validate if layoutManager and orientation of recyclerview are fine because maybe they are not visible by orientation.
Not evil practice, use case specify that large of the list change to 1 depending of the filter value, even filterable adapters works with item count

For some reason when I click the button the list.size changes from 4 at start to 0, which I believe is causing the issue. I am not sure why this is happening.

Am I not supposed to use the getItemCount() code above if I want to change the visibility from 1 to say 4? I'm confused by the wording.

If size is zero means list inside of your adapter was replaced by empty list in some point of execution.
Could you attach code of your button click listener, adapter initialization on fragment and adapter?
Code of getItemCount() is for change number of elements of recyclerView depending of isViewAllEnabled value.
Initially isViewAllEnabled will be false, then item count could be 0 if list is empty or 1 if list is not empty (Only first position).
After press button ViewAll isViewAllEnabled will be true, then item count will be list.size (real size of list)

I can't really share too much. I implemented your code verbatum. I am not sure why the size would change to 0 as I don't have anything that changes the list. It actually doesn't change the output as I always see just the 1st item position. The only thing I see different is that you have a boolean on getItemCount() and Kotlin makes me change it to INT.

I am pretty sure there is a better solution. For example, add your items after the button is clicked. Anyway in your case you can create var allItemsVisible = false. Then change your logic like this:
if (position == 0) {
    view.foo.visibility  = View.VISIBLE 
}
else {
    if (allItemsVisible) {
        view.foo.visibility  = View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        view.foo.visibility  = View.GONE
    }
}

And in your activity in your button onClick make adapter.allItemsVisible = true and don't forget to call notifyDataSetChanged() to apply changes.
Hope it helps.

Thank you for your quick answer. I tried this and onCreate it is displaying correctly. When I do:  viewAll.setOnClickListener { adapter.allItemsVisible = true } it does not appear to trigger anything. Am I missing something in this statement?
